# Java Spring Security with OpenId Provider

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, openid-connect, openid-provider

I have a spring MVC application.Another client application want access my spring app using open id connect. How to implement open id provider in server side.Please help.

Comment: see http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Comment: any specific library for spring security

Comment: I only found the word 'spring' there once and its in Java: http://kit.mit.edu/projects/mitreid-connect

Comment: any other default spring security functionality available.

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of. Did you Google for it? In your original question you did not show any sign for research, which is very appreciated and looked for in StackOverflow.

Comment: ya.. not find any fesible solution. thatz y posted here.

Comment: In that case you should tell us where you looked and what you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MITREid Connect** **[OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server)** is an OpenID Connect implementation on the Spring platform.

I'm afraid that **[Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth)** project won't be able to support OpenID Connect because it will require big changes in design. See [Issue 619](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/619), for example.

In general, a typical OAuth 2.0 server implementation assumes that a value of `response_type` parameter contained in an authorization request is either `code` or `token` (although RFC 6749 mentions the possibility that the parameter may take multiple values at a time). However, **[OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)** and **[OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html)** have invalidated the assumption explicitly. Now, `response_type` parameter can be any combination of `code`, `token` and `id_token`, or `none`. This has a big impact on existing OAuth 2.0 server implementations. Personally, as a matter of fact, I once discarded my OAuth 2.0 server implementation and rewrote it from scratch to support OpenID Connect.

Comment: [Spring Security 5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login) now supports OpenID Connect